# How to Return Expression<Func<TClass, TClassField>> when given only FieldInfo and TClass?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

In runtime I have only `TClass` and a `FieldInfo`, and I need to generate a lambda expression that gets an instance of `TClass` and returns the correlate field. After constructing a `MemberExpression` I got stuck when trying to wrap the expression to  `Expression<Func<TClass, TClassField>>`:

```
var res = Expression.Lambda<Func<TClass, TClassField>>(memberExpression, paramExp);
return res;
```

Because TClassField is not known during compile time. I need some strongly typed solution (no casting to `object`) due to 3rd party requirements. Is this even possible in C#?

EDIT I need something like this -

```
private void User3rdPartyLibrary<TClass>(FieldInfo fi)
{
    //Goal: call _3rdParty.Method<TClass, TClassField>(expression)

    var memberExp = Expression.Field(Expression.Parameter(typeof(TClass)), fi);
    //var lambda = some magic that returns  Expression.Lambda<Func<TClass, TClassField>>
    //      where fi.FieldType == typeof(TClassField).

    //_3rdParty.Method(lambda);
}
```

Signature of the 3rd party method:

```
public void Method<TClass, TClassMember>(Expression<Func<TClass, TClassMember>> expression);
```

Comment: If you have MethodInfo, then you can call MakeGenericMethod and pass generic attribute, and it will generate generic method

Comment: can you add more code for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please see the added code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void User3rdPartyLibrary<TClass>( FieldInfo fi )
{
    // check types; add descriptions to exceptions
    if( fi.ReflectedType != typeof( TClass ) )
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    var pe = Expression.Parameter( typeof( TClass ) );
    var me = Expression.Field( pe, fi );
    var memberExpression = Expression.Lambda( me, pe );

    // GetMethod call inlined for illustrative purposes
    typeof( ThirdPartyClass ).GetMethod( "ThirdPartyMethod" )
        .MakeGenericMethod( typeof( TClass ), fi.FieldType )
        .Invoke( memberExpression );
}
```

Then call using reflection:

```
FieldInfo fi = <whatever>;

// again, GetMethod call inlined for illustrative purposes
typeof( YourType ).GetMethod( "User3rdPartyLibrary" )
    .MakeGenericMethod( fi.ReflectedType )
    .Invoke( fi );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have already solved the problem using @Sergey_Litvinov's comment, and the result is very similar to your answer. For future readers, I will mark this as an answer :)